# Optimization with endogenous constraint

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I have the following optimization problem:
\begin{align}
 \max_{x,y,z} \quad 
 & ax + by + cz\\
 \text{subject to} \quad 
 & z \leq xy\\
 & z \leq L \\
    & x + y = M
\end{align}
The KKT conditions yield FOC:
\begin{align}
    a+\lambda_1 y - \lambda_3 &= 0\\
    b+\lambda_1 x - \lambda_3 &= 0\\
    c-\lambda_1-\lambda_2 &=0\\
    \lambda_1(xy-z) &=0\\
    \lambda_2(L-z) &=0
\end{align}
Let $a,b,c>0$, and $a\neq b$.

From Eqs. 1 and 2,
$$a+\lambda_1 y = b+\lambda_1 x \implies \lambda_1 \neq 0$$
But then Eq. 4 implies $z=xy$. Yet if we suppose $L=0$, clearly $z=0$, but $xy \neq 0$.

I'm fairly sure I violated some assumption of KKT conditions with my "endogenous" constraint, but two hours of googling got me nowhere. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Why does supposing $L = 0$ imply that $xy \ne 0$?

Comment: I'm sorry - my wording was poor.

Comment: As I'm typing out my response, I realize where I went wrong. In the event that $L=0$, the maximum value of the objective function would be realized by setting the variable multiplied by the larger of $a$ or $b$ to equal $M$ and the other to 0, so $xy$ **would** be 0. Thank you @GabeHackebeil!

Answer (score 0):

This question is based on an incorrect assumption. In the event that $L=0$, the maximum value of the objective function would be realized by setting the variable ($x$ or $y$) multiplied by the larger of $a$ or $b$ to equal $M$, and the other to 0, so $xy$ would be 0.